# Access form not running on open (error 2001)

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I have an Access database that is supposed to create laboratory reports - worked fine for the last several years - but now I am running into a weird issue. Full disclosure, I didn't build this database and while I'm well versed in this particular database, I'm far less familiar with VBA or building Access databases on my own.

My database is supposed to open with a form (my "Switchboard"), a simple two option selection - open a configuration form or open a batch creation form.

```
    Option Compare Database

    Private Sub Option1_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm ("CreateBatch")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Option2_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm ("Configuration")
    End Sub
```

The database is not opening that initial Switchboard form, and I'm getting a Macro Single Step message box indicating error 2001 and the only button not greyed out on the box is Stop All Macros.

After stopping macros, if I manually open the SwitchBoard, no error and the database runs fine. If I jump straight to my CreateBatch form, where I enter file locations for other necessary files for down stream processes, I get a run-time error #76 Path not found (before this error started, I could skip the Switchboard form without issue). If I stop macros then compact and repair, runs fine including auto-opening the Switchboard, until the next time I open the database, then the 2001 error comes back. I have also repaired and reinstalled Office, to no avail - all the same error triggers.

Database file location and sub-folders are included in trusted locations list, all macros are enabled, I am the only user of this database, and it is only used on the one computer.

Here's where it's really weird for me. I get the 2001 error if I open the database from Access (via File/Open), but not if I open the database directly from the file location. Back up versions do the same - fine if I open from the file location, error if I open from Access.

Database still works, albeit now with an extra, manual step or different method of opening, but I'm still flummoxed why the auto-open form is running into issues when I open the database one way but not the other.

Comment: What's the error **text**?

Comment: The message box includes - Macro name: Switchboard : Form : OnOpen : Embedded Macro.  Condition: (none listed). Action Name: SetTempVar. Arguments: SwitchboardID, DLookUp("SwitchboardID","Switchboard Items","[ItemNumber] = 0 AND [Argument] = 'Default'"). Error Number: 2001

Comment: You mention macros but show VBA. How is Switchboard opened - AutoExec macro or db Options?

Comment: It's an AutoExec macro.